# Proper way of Mavenizing a C++ Multi-module project with multiple variations of modules?

Tags: maven

Maybe I am trying to shove a round-peg into a square hole (as some of my research suggests) but I could not find any way to properly confirm or deny if what I am trying to do is possible or reasonable with Maven. Sadly, changing the nature of the project is not an option. Sorry for being verbose, but I want to make sure I explain the situation properly. I am somewhat of a maven newbie as well.

I have a multi-module project whose deliverable is separate .exe files for each of those modules. This project has different features depending on the client. Most are the same but some modules will include or exclude certain parts of code.

Hyper-Simplified Example

- Client A

  - Module1
  - Module2

    - has feature x, feature y
- Client B

  - Module1
  - Module2

    - has feature x, feature z

Currently, it is built with some batch files calling msbuild on pre-configured VisualStudio projects, which have the individual feature's source folders added to them.

Is there Maven-ish way of building the different versions individually without having to store the duplicate code like this example below?

```
project
 +- root
 |  +- pom.xml
 +- Module1
 |  +- pom.xml
 |  +- src 
 |  |  +- main
 |  |  |  +- c++
 |  |  |  +- include
 + Module2A
 |  +- pom.xml
 |  +- src 
 |  |  +- main
 |  |  |  +- c++
 |  |  |  |    +- feature x
 |  |  |  |    +- feature y
 |  |  |  +- include
 + Module2B
 |  +- pom.xml
 |   +- src
 |  |  +- main
 |  |  |  +- c++
 |  |  |  |    +- feature x
 |  |  |  |    +- feature z
 |  |  |  +- include
```

Module2A and Module2B would both need to output Module2.exe

Ways that I have looked into possibly trying to use are profiles or some kind of inherited pom structure but neither seem to fit the bill. I really appreciate any insight someone has of techniques or plug-ins to help with this.

Comment: First I would really reconsider the idea of using Maven for C++ based builds. apart from that you could take a look at http://maven-nar.github.io/ ?

Comment: khmarbaise - Sorry for not mentioning this in the question. I am already using maven-nar plugin. Overall the build part more or less works, apart from those few modules that contain different features based on the client.

Comment: From an architectural view I would separate those things from Modul2A-Feature x and Feature Y into separete modules..shouldn't that solve the problem?

Comment: The features themselves do not have any inherent output of their own, other than being extra classes compiled into Module2's nar. So would it be possible to still consider them a module?